# Symfony returns 301 on requested url by cUrl

Tags: php, symfony

So, i have REST api on my project

I am trying to make request to API with cUrl. But Symfony returns 301

routing:

```
CMContestBundle_api_new:
type: rest
pattern:  /{_locale}/api/contest/new/
defaults: { _controller: CMContestBundle:API:new, _locale: en }
requirements:
    _method: GET
```

security

```
- { path: ^/(en|no|dk|se|es|it|pl)/api/contest/new, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods : GET }
```

curl request

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET  http://localhost/app_dev.php/en/api/contest/new
```

when i enter this url in browser - everything is ok. but if this is curl request it returns 301 and html page which redirects on requested url

any ideas why symfony returns 301 instead of right response?

Comment: post the output of curl with request and response headers

Comment: try url `http://localhost/app_dev.php/en/api/contest/new/` with `/` at end. Please tell the page where you redirected

Answer (score 0):

As @forgottenbas mentioned, you must add `/` at the end of the url. But you can also add `-L` switch to `curl` so it follows the redirects like this:

```
curl -v -H -L "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET  http://localhost/app_dev.php/en/api/contest/new
```